# C++ Visual Studio 2013 - additional include directories priority

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm migrating a Visual C++ 6.0 project to Visual Studio 2013. After solving many issues I'm stucked at the following problem. I have in my project path a folder with windows sdk `.h` files ( not all `.h`. files ). 
In the old project I've had in additional include directories the following path : `..\..\sdk\include` and the project builds succesfully. But, when I try to add the same path in Visual Studio 2013 I have over 100 errors regarding one of the header files from the sdk folder. (`undeclared identifier`)

My question is, how do I configure the Visual Studio project in order to search first in `..\..\sdk\include` for some of the windows sdk files and then into the default windows sdk folder ?

Comment: Try first with a static path name and then correct your relative path

Comment: Do **not** copy SDK files, surely those copies are ancient and no longer compatible with the current SDK version.  Get rid of them.